# Basic C++ code for multiplication of two matrices or vectors

Tags: c++, math, vector, matrix

I got some code off the Internet and now I just need help to multiply elements of two matrices or vectors.

```
Matrixf multiply(Matrixf const& left, Matrixf const& right) {

    // Error check
    if (left.ncols() != right.nrows()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Unable to multiply: matrix dimensions not agree.");
    }

    /* I have all the other part of the code for matrix */

    /** Now I am not sure how to implement multiplication of a vector or matrix. **/

    Matrixf ret(1, 1);

    return ret;
}
```

Background: I am a new C++ user and I am also doing a major in mathematics, so thought I would try implement a simple calculator.

Comment: In a comment below, you said that you want to improve your "coding knowledge" but at the same time you said that you got some code from the internet. Perhaps you should try implementing a Matrix Class from scratch.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to build my knowledge by doing easy methods first, which is why I took the matrix ops source code which is beyond my understanding atm. I am trying to do a simple method as above first.

Comment: @Ice: Trying to use code you don't understand at all will not improve your knowledge, and this is not an "easy" method. If you want to learn, implement your own matrix class from scratch and write your own multiplication routines. This will be a much better exercise.

Comment: I would expect a math major to understand linear algebra.    I'd recommend that you start with a Vector class.  Implement addition, subtraction, normalization, dot product methods.  Then do the same for Matrix.  Build up slowly.  Write unit tests for each method.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'd recommend you use a library such as [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) (very fast) or the [Boost uBLAS matrix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) (not so fast, relatively speaking) class.  Still, if you're trying to learn the way to do this, there's no harm in building your own class.  The standard way of doing this is with templates for the type.  You can also, with a little bit of further investigation use templates for the size (left as an exercise to the reader).

```
template <typename T> class matrix
{
private:
    T *_m;
    std::size_t _rows;
    std::size_t _cols;

public:
    matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols)
      : _m(new T[rows*cols]), _rows(rows), _cols(cols) {}

    matrix(matrix<T>&& src)
      : _m(src._m), _rows(src._rows), _cols(src._cols)
    {
        src._m = NULL;
        src._rows = 0;
        src._cols = 0;
    }

    matrix<T>& operator=(matrix<T>&& src)
    {
        delete[] this->_m;
        this->_m = src._m;
        this->_rows = src._rows;
        this->_cols = src._cols;
        src._m = NULL;
        src._rows = 0;
        src._cols = 0;

        return *this;
    }

    virtual ~matrix()
    {
        delete[] this->_m;
    }

    inline float& operator()(std::size_t r, std::size_t c)
    {
        assert(r < this->_rows && c < this->_cols);
        return this->_m[r*this->_cols + c];
    }

    inline std::size_t rows() { return this->_rows; }
    inline std::size_t cols() { return this->_cols; }
};

template <typename T>
matrix<T> operator*(const matrix<T>& l, const matrix<T>& r)
{
    assert(l.cols() == r.rows());
    matrix<T> rv(l.rows(), r.cols());

    for (std::size_t r = 0; r < rv.rows(); ++r)
        for (std::size_t c = 0; c < rv.cols(); ++c);
        {
            rv(r, c) = (T) 0;
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < l.cols(); ++i)
                rv(r, c) += l(r, i) * r(i, c);
        }

    return rv;
}
```

This has a few [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) aspects to it, namely the move constructor and assignment operator.  If you are not using C++11 yet, replace them with traditional copy and assignment operators respectively.  Also, this is a kind of naive multiplier.  There are some efficiencies you can employ to eliminate many of the matrix element lookups by replacing them with an iterator style construct instead.

Comment: Be warned, I just typed it in; I haven't tried to compile it.

Comment: A library will be a good idea eventually, but the only way to learn how to build wheels is to reinvent them.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is hard to work off (as an outsider), since we need to know how the class `Matrixf` works. I will outline a method anyway, which may point you in the right direction. The simplest way you could represent a matrix in C/C++ is simply a 2D array of floating points like so:

```
float matrix[3][3]; // 3x3 Matrix
```

Considering you already know the maths, I think all you need is some guidance in terms of coding what you need. To multiply elements of two of these matrices simply do this:

```
matrixC[0][1] = matrixA[0][0] * matrixB[0][0];
```

This will store the result of multiplying the top-left element of `matrixA` and the top-left element of `matrixB` in the top-middle element of `matrixC`. Essentially the first square bracket represents the *row* and the second square bracket represents the *column* (however it is totally up to you which order you want the rows and columns to be, just so long as you stay consistent).

Vectors can be represented similarly:

```
float vector[3]; // 3d vector
```

Of course, since we are using C++, there are nicer ways to do this. It seems you have some resources that describe a class-centric method to doing this. The nice thing about a class based method is you can abstract multiplication operations in a neat manner like this:

```
Matrix3x3f matrix( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );

Vector3f   vector( 0.2f, 1.4f, -3.1f );

matrix.multVec( vector );
```

...or something along these lines.

(It is also worth mentioning that there are libraries out there that already do this sort of thing, and efficiently too.)

Comment: In your answer you could also mention some aspects of the (typical) underlying hardware, like the general goodness of sequential memory access (relevant for matrix element accesses). (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having a look at the source of the [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net) C++ matrix library. While large, it is quite readable.

In particular, have a look at the "gemm.hpp" file, which implements matrix/matrix multiplication, and "gemv.hpp" which implements matrix/vector multiplication. The files "Mat_bones.hpp" and "Mat_meat.hpp" provide the root matrix class.